# Netbeans IDE 8.1 warning for Class Length

Tags: netbeans-8

I'm using Netbeans IDE 8.1 version for MVC (Codeigniter). In Model i'm getting warning like Class Length is 251 Lines (200 allowed). 
What is exact meaning of this warning and if not resolved, then what exactly will happen ?

Answer (score 2):

First, this warning is nothing to do with CodeIgniter. NetBeans is simply giving you a friendly advisory warning that your PHP class is more than 200 lines long (251 lines in your case).

Nothing bad will happen if you get that message, but you may or may not appreciate it. Either way, it can be configured as follows:

- The message can be suppressed entirely if it is considered unhelpful.
- Alternatively, the message can be shown as an "Info", "Warning" or "Error" message. By default it is a warning message.
- The number of lines allowed before the message is displayed can be adjusted up or down as desired. The default is 200 lines.

Configure the message as follows:

- **Tools** menu -> **Options** -> click the **Editor** icon -> click the **Hints** tab.
- Select **PHP** from the **Language** drop list.
- Select the **Too Many Lines** node from the list of message categories, and expand it.
- Simply uncheck **Class Declaration** if you don't want to see the message at all.
- Otherwise, select the severity of the message from the **Show As** drop list, and adjust the default line threshold of 200 if appropriate.

Here's the configuration screen:
[image: PHP class length configuration]

Finally, note that these configuration settings are global. I don't believe it is possible to customize the message individually for each PHP project.